# DateTime from .NET to smalldatetime in SQL - how to do queries?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I have a `DateTime` component in my code, and I want to use it for a query in my SQL Server database.

When inserting this component, there seems to be no problem, but when querying for `smalldatetime` values, I just don't know how to do it. The dataset is always empty.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "ReadDates"; 

dataset = new DataSet();

SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);
parameter.Value = DateTime.Now();
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
return dataset;
```

And this is in my stored procedure:

```
select * from TableDates
where ValueDate <= @date
```

So I have no problems running the procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, when entering a parameter in this format: `'2000-03-03 04:05:01'`, but when passing a `DateTime`, the query is always empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show your *complete* stored procedure declaration, including the parameter declaration?

Comment: Or if you're using SQL 2012 you can `CAST(@Date AS DATE)` for both `ValueDate` and `@date` to ensure the time component is stripped.

Comment: @CR41G14: that's probably the **WORST EVER** advice! If you have a `DateTime` - you should try to use **native** date/time datatypes whenever possible to **avoid** converting back and forth to a string!

Comment: @DarthContinent is correct `select * from TableDates
where CAST(ValueDate AS DATE) <= @date`

Comment: Just as a side hint - in your example, the time part was '04:05:01'. according to MSDN, System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallDateTime ignores the seconds, so maybe you should use System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime instead. Source - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: @OnoSendai: tried it, didn't help. Darth Contintent: sorry, SQL 2008

Comment: Ok, try this then: Instead of passing DateTime.Now() to parameter.Value, try System.DateTime.Now.Date. This will feed the date part only.

Comment: Doesn't `CAST(@Date AS DATE)` work on SQL 2008 as well? I know it works on 2008R2.

Comment: `parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallDateTime`? Perhaps the DbType is getting reset when setting the value.

Comment: Well CAST works, but still doesn't help the problem. Also tried passing the DateTime.Now.Date, now help.

Comment: If you create a stored procedure that simply prints the smallDateTime parameter, does that work?

Comment: Can you please provide the actual code?  The current code has at least 1 compile time error - `parameter.Value = DateTime.Now();` should be `parameter.Value = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: Really ugly but can you try sending this instead of Datetime.Now? new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, ((DateTime.Now.Second + (DateTime.Now.Millisecond / 1000)) > 29.998) ? DateTime.Now.Minute + 1 : DateTime.Now.Minute, 0);

Answer (score 2):

I tried it by using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Here is the example stored procedure i wrote:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ShowGivenSmallDateTimeValue] 
    @givenSmallDateTime smalldatetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Simply return the given small date time value back to sender.
    SELECT @givenSmallDateTime
END
```

And here is the C# code to execute the procedure:

```
var connectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connectionBuilder.DataSource = "localhost\\sqlexpress";
connectionBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionBuilder.ConnectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand())
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "ShowGivenSmallDateTimeValue";
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@givenSmallDateTime", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime) { Value = now });

    connection.Open();
    var result = (DateTime)command.ExecuteScalar();
    var difference = result - now;

    Console.WriteLine("Due to the smalldatetime roundings we have a difference of " + difference + ".");
}
```

And it simply works.

Comment: So it looks like the difference is that you never explicitly set the parameter's `DBType` to `SqlDbType.SmallDateTime`.  If you add that, does it fail?

Comment: @mbeckish: Just adopted my example code and it makes no difference in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code for creating the SqlParameter for a Datetime; For SQL Server 2008 we pass the value as datetime2 since SQL will implicity convert from datetime2 to every other date type so long as it is within the range of the target type...

```
            // Default conversion is now DateTime to datetime2. The ADO.Net default is to use datetime. 
            // This appears to be a safe change as any datetime parameter will accept a datetime2 so long as the value is within the
            // range for a datetime. Hence this code is acceptable for both datetime and datetime2 parameters, whereas datetime is not 
            // (because it doesn't handle the full range of datetime2).
            SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter(name, SqlDbType.DateTime2);
```

Answer (score -2):

Since Your parameter includes zeros in day and month parts...sql server converts it but doest match to your date.... i.e.,

if DATETIME.now() returns '2000-03-03 04:05:01'... it is casted into 2000-3-3 Without including zeros...so u need to specify zeros also to match your date.

Comment: "Zeros"? I don't see what that has to do with it.